# How to detect and fix incorrect character encoding

Tags: utf-8, iso-8859-1

A upstream service reads a stream of UTF-8 bytes, *assumes* they are ISO-8859-1, applies ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 encoding, and sends them to my service, labeled as UTF-8.

The upstream service is out of my control. They may fix it, it may never be fixed.

I know that I can fix the encoding by applying UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 encoding then labeling the bytes as UTF-8. But what happens if my upstream fixes their issue?

Is there any way to detect this issue and fix the encoding only when I find a bad encoding?

I'm also not *sure* that the upstream encoding is ISO-8859-1. I think the upstream is perl so that encoding makes sense and each sample I've tried decoded correctly when I apply ISO-8859-1 encoding.

---

When the source sends `e4 9c 94` (✔) to my upstream, my upstream sends me `c3 a2 c2 9c c2 94` (â).

- utf-8 string `✔` as bytes: `e4 9c 94`
- bytes `e4 9c 94` as latin1 string: `â`
- utf-8 string `â` as bytes: c3 a2 c2 9c c2 94

I can fix it applying `upstream.encode('ISO-8859-1').force_encoding('UTF-8')` but it will break as soon as the upstream issue is fixed.

Comment: Interesting note, stackoverflow renders e4 9c 94 as three characters (`â` and two empty squares) in the editor and preview but as one character on this page.

Comment: There is really no good solution to this. You have to KNOW the data is mangled and HOW it was mangled in order to reverse it. I mean, you *could* decode the UTF-8 once, and if the resulting Unicode codepoints *resemble* the bit pattern of UTF-8 then decode again. But that is risky. I would probably just implement the double-decoding and put it inside a configurable flag, as well as a configurable charset (in case the mangling is not always using ISO-8859-1) and when you KNOW the upstream has been fixed then just turn the flag off.

Comment: Typo: `✔` is `e2 9c 94`

Comment: Character codes in the range 0x80-0x9F are unprintable in ISO 8859-1. Some fonts display them as empty boxes, others as completely invisible characters. There is no well-defined standard or canonical graphical representation for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know how it is mangled, you can try to unmangle it by decoding the received UTF-8 bytes, encoding to latin1, and decoding as UTF-8 again.  Only your mangled strings, pure ASCII strings, or very unlikely latin-1 string combinations will successfully decode twice.  If that decoding fails, assume the upstream was fixed and just decode once as UTF-8.  A pure ASCII string will correctly decode with either method so there is no issue there as well.  There are valid UTF-8-encoded sequences that survive a double-decode but they are unlikely to occur in normal text.

Here's an example in Python (you didn't mention a language...):

```py
    # Assume bytes are latin1, but return encoded UTF-8.
    def bad(b):
        return b.decode('latin1').encode('utf8')
    
    # Assume bytes are UTF-8, and pass them along.
    def good(b):
        return b
    
    def decoder(b):
        try:
            return b.decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
        except UnicodeError:
            return b.decode('utf8')
    
    b = '✔'.encode('utf8')
    print(decoder(bad(b)))
    print(decoder(good(b)))
```

Output:

```
✔
✔
```

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't had more upvotes. In my case, my script is sometimes fed cp1252 encoded as UTF8 - for instance, `Ø` becomes `Ã˜`. This snippet became the basis for a "maybe_fix_encoding" function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on Mark Tolonen's answer, again in Python 3:

```py
    def maybe_fix_encoding(utf8_string, possible_codec="cp1252"):
        """Attempts to fix mangled text caused by interpreting UTF8 as cp1252
        (or other codec: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html)"""
        try:
            return utf8_string.encode(possible_codec).decode('utf8')
        except UnicodeError:
            return utf8_string
```

```py
>>> maybe_fix_encoding("some normal text and some scandinavian characters Ã¦ Ã¸ Ã¥ Ã† Ã˜ Ã…")
'some normal text and some scandinavian characters æ ø å Æ Ø Å'
```

Answer (score 1):

Bare ISO 8859-1 is almost guaranteed to be invalid UTF-8. Attempting to decode as ISO 8859-1 and then as UTF-8, and falling back to simply decoding as UTF-8 if this produces invalid byte sequences should work for this specific case.

In some more detail, the UTF-8 encoding severely restricts which non-ASCII character sequences are allowed. The allowed patterns are extremely unlikely in ISO-8859-1 because in this encoding, they represent sequences like `Ã` followed by an unprintable control character or mathematical operator, which simply do not tend to occur in any valid text.

Comment: Next thing you know some genius decides to call their "web 3.0 artificial intelligence crowdsourcing blockchain" company *Ãƒâ€šÃ‚*

Answer (score 0):

Based on [turpachull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1278406/turpachull)'s answer, and the [python3 list of standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) (& [Mark Amery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709587/mark-amery)'s [answer listing the set for various versions of python](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25584253/)), here's a script that will attempt every encoding transform on stdin and output each version if it's different from the plain `utf_8`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import fileinput

encodings = ["ascii", "big5hkscs", "cp1006", "cp1125", "cp1250", "cp1252", "cp1254", "cp1256", "cp1258", "cp273", "cp437", "cp720", "cp775", "cp852", "cp856", "cp858", "cp861", "cp863", "cp865", "cp869", "cp875", "cp949", "euc_jis_2004", "euc_kr", "gbk", "hz", "iso2022_jp_1", "iso2022_jp_2004", "iso2022_jp_ext", "iso8859_11", "iso8859_14", "iso8859_16", "iso8859_3", "iso8859_5", "iso8859_7", "iso8859_9", "koi8_r", "koi8_u", "latin_1", "mac_cyrillic", "mac_iceland", "mac_roman", "ptcp154", "shift_jis_2004", "utf_16_be", "utf_32", "utf_32_le", "utf_7", "utf_8_sig", "big5", "cp037", "cp1026", "cp1140", "cp1251", "cp1253", "cp1255", "cp1257", "cp424", "cp500", "cp737", "cp850", "cp855", "cp857", "cp860", "cp862", "cp864", "cp866", "cp874", "cp932", "cp950", "euc_jisx0213", "euc_jp", "gb18030", "gb2312", "iso2022_jp", "iso2022_jp_2", "iso2022_jp_3", "iso2022_kr", "iso8859_10", "iso8859_13", "iso8859_15", "iso8859_2", "iso8859_4", "iso8859_6", "iso8859_8", "johab", "koi8_t", "kz1048", "mac_greek", "mac_latin2", "mac_turkish", "shift_jis", "shift_jisx0213", "utf_16", "utf_16_le", "utf_32_be", "utf_8"]

def maybe_fix_encoding(utf8_string, possible_codec="utf_8"):
  try:
    return utf8_string.encode(possible_codec).decode('utf_8')
  except UnicodeError:
    return utf8_string

for line in sys.stdin:
  for e in encodings:
    i=line.rstrip('\n')
    result=maybe_fix_encoding(i, e)
    if result != i or e == 'utf_8':
      print("\t".join([e, result]))
  print("\n")
```

usage e.g.:

```
$ echo 'Requiem der morgenrÃ¶te' | ~/decode_string.py
cp1252  Requiem der morgenröte
cp1254  Requiem der morgenröte
iso2022_jp_1    Requiem der morgenr(D**B"yte
iso2022_jp_2    Requiem der morgenr(D**B"yte
iso2022_jp_2004 Requiem der morgenr(Q):B"yte
iso2022_jp_3    Requiem der morgenr(O):B"yte
iso2022_jp_ext  Requiem der morgenr(D**B"yte
latin_1 Requiem der morgenröte
iso8859_9   Requiem der morgenröte
iso8859_14  Requiem der morgenröte
iso8859_15  Requiem der morgenröte
mac_iceland Requiem der morgenr̦te
mac_roman   Requiem der morgenr̦te
mac_turkish Requiem der morgenr̦te
utf_7   Requiem der morgenr+AMMAtg-te
utf_8   Requiem der morgenrÃ¶te
utf_8_sig   Requiem der morgenrÃ¶te
```